# Quotes issue in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to refresh an img element within a div every 5 seconds that would indicate whether the user is connected to the internet or not connected. If the user is connected, it will display an image online, but if the user is offline, a local image will display.

However, I cannot get around this quote problem. I even tried the "&-quot;" thing (without the dash) and it still will not work. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.setInterval("refreshDiv()", 5000);
    function refreshDiv(){
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "<img id="this" src="http://stallionware.weebly.com/uploads/3/0/4/3/30431988/4901948_orig.png" onerror="this.src='nowifi.png'">";
}
</script>
<div id=wifi>
<img id="this" src="http://stallionware.weebly.com/uploads/3/0/4/3/30431988/4901948_orig.png" onerror="this.src='nowifi.png'">
</div>
```

I do not have the desire to use jQuery or Ajax or any server-side languages because this is all on a local machine.

Comment: I'm very sure you can do `document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML`

Comment: @vihan1086 I have actually tried that, but then instead of displaying an image, it displays some text saying what kind of object I'm referencing to is.

Answer (score 7):

You can escape those double quotes like this:

```
document.getElementById("this").innerHTML = "<img id=\"this\" src=\"http://stallionware.weebly.com/uploads/3/0/4/3/30431988/4901948_orig.png\" onerror=\"this.src='nowifi.png'\">";
```

By typing `\"` you're telling the JavaScript that you want to insert a double quote inside your string. The other option you have is to use single quotes instead. (I've changed your getElementById from 'test' to 'this' since your HTML has no 'test' as Id)

Also, you shouldn't call a function using a string as you did on `refreshDiv`. Instead you should call its name like this:

```
window.setInterval(refreshDiv, 5000);
```

Comment: I applied your method, but it will not refresh.

Comment: Its because you defined <img id="this"> on the HTML and tried to getElementById ("test"). Theres no Id "test". I will fix it

Comment: Oddly, it still did not do the trick... should I create an onload attribute somewhere?

Comment: The problem seems to be that "innetHtml". You're inserting another <img> tag inside the tag you already have

Answer (score 0):

You should use a hierarchy of single quotes and double quotes. Using double quotes under double quotes makes the JS think is a combination of strings. But it fails without the operators.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.setInterval("refreshDiv()", 5000);
    function refreshDiv(){
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = '<img id="this" src="http://stallionware.weebly.com/uploads/3/0/4/3/30431988/4901948_orig.png" onerror="this.src='nowifi.png'">';
}
</script>
<div id=wifi>
<img id="this" src="http://stallionware.weebly.com/uploads/3/0/4/3/30431988/4901948_orig.png" onerror="this.src='nowifi.png'">
</div>
```

Apart from that rather than checking every 5 seconds I would suggest going and using online and offline events of browser - which then saves your code from having `setInterval` kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, you can use single-quotes or double-quotes. For your case, you should put the string containing the div in single-quotes and have the HTML attributes within that string using double-quotes. However, it looks like you have a few other mistakes in your code anyway. Try this:

```
<img id="image" src="http://stallionware.weebly.com/uploads/3/0/4/3/30431988/4901948_orig.png" onerror="error">
```

with the following in your Javascript:

```
var theImage = document.getElementById('image');
function error() {
  theImage.src='nowifi.png';
}

function refreshDiv(){
  theImage.innerHTML = '<img id="image" src="http://stallionware.weebly.com/uploads/3/0/4/3/30431988/4901948_orig.png"     
  onerror="error">';
}
setInterval(refreshDiv, 5000);
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to refresh, nor call upon the local image.